# How to find time difference/lag between two audio signals?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, delay, timedelay

I need to find the time difference/lag between two audio signals.

Background Info: It is a sample multimedia application, which has a server and a client. A .mp3 file will be sent as streaming data to client. Two TI boards are used one as server and other as client. The server board will also listen, and client will also listen. Here I need to find difference between these two audio signals from remote and local client.
OS used : Linux

I found Audacity tool to capture signals. whether it has capability to capture the two signals and find difference between them ?
(or)
whether cross correlation has to performed to find difference between them ?

Any ideas are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-correlation is the usual method - the location of the peak will give you the lag. Since this is more a DSP question than a programming question you might want to go to http://dsp.stackexchange.com for any further questions on this subject.

Comment: I've done it in Blender: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48271/2843 - there is a link to an Add-on in my question which includes a Wave-Sync-Tool in C.